# Will flip an image change the image dimension

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image and its mask picked from a competition hosted in kaggle. The shape of the image is `(512,512,3)` and the mask is `(512,512,1)`. After applying a `function(flipping)` on an image, the shape remains the same. However, before applying the operation when I try to access the mask such as `(print mask[:,:,0])`, I get a matrix,

```
  [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
   ...
   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

but after applying the operation, and try to access the mask `(print mask[:,:,0]),` I get the following error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "Augmentation.py", line 94, in <module>
 plot_img_and_mask_transformed(img,mask,img_flip,mask_flip)
 File "Augmentation.py", line 36, in plot_img_and_mask_transformed
   print(mask_tr[:,:,0])
 IndexError: too many indices for array
```

The function I applied was

```
 def random_flip(img,mask,u=0.5):

   if np.random.random() < u :
      img = cv.flip(img,0)
      mask = cv.flip(mask,0)
   return img, mask

img, mask = get_image_and_mask(img_id)
img_tr,mask_tr = random_flip(img,mask)
plot(img,mask,img_tr,mask_tr)
```

The shape of the image and the mask before flipping

```
  ((512, 512, 3), (512, 512, 1))
```

The shape of the image and the mask after flipping

```
  ((512, 512, 3), (512, 512))
```

Can someone help me out what's happening behind the scenes?

### CODE

```
def get_image_and_mask(img_id):
  img = image.load_img(join(data_dir,'train','%s.jpg' % img_id),target_size=(input_size,input_size))
  img = image.img_to_array(img)
  mask = image.load_img(join(data_dir,'train_masks','%s_mask.gif' % img_id), grayscale=True,target_size=(input_size,input_size))
  mask = image.img_to_array(mask)
  img,mask = img / 255., mask/ 255.
  return img, mask

def plot_img_and_mask(img,mask):
  fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10,5),sharex=True,sharey=True)
  axs[0].imshow(img)
  axs[1].imshow(mask[:,:,0])
  for ax in axs:
     ax.set_xlim(0,input_size)
     ax.axis('off')
  fig.tight_layout()
  plt.show()

def plot_img_and_mask_transformed(img, mask, img_tr, mask_tr):
 fig, axs=plt.subplots(ncols=4,figsize=(16,4),sharex=True,sharey=True)
 axs[0].imshow(img)

 axs[1].imshow(mask[:,:,0])
 print(mask[:,:,0])
 print(mask_tr[:,:,0])
 axs[2].imshow(img_tr)
 axs[3].imshow(mask_tr)

 for ax in axs:
    ax.set_xlim(0,input_size)
    ax.axis('off')

 fig.tight_layout()
 plt.show()

def random_flip(img,mask,u=0.5):
  # Why do we have to check less than u
  if np.random.random() < u :
     img = cv.flip(img,0)
     mask = cv.flip(mask,0)
  return img, mask


def rotate(x,theta,row_axis=0,col_axis=1,channel_axis=2,fill_mode='nearest',cval=0):
 rotation_matrix = np.array([
  [np.cos(theta),-np.sin(theta),0],
  [np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta),0],
  [0,0,1]
 ])

 h, w = x.shape[row_axis], x.shape[col_axis]
 transform_matrix = image.transform_matrix_offset_center(rotation_matrix,h,w)
 x = image.apply_transform(x,transform_matrix,channel_axis,fill_mode,cval)
 return x

def random_rotate(img, mask, rotate_limit=(-20,20), u=0.5):
   if np.random.random() <  u:
     theta = np.pi/ 180 * np.random.uniform(rotate_limit[0], rotate_limit[1])
     img = rotate(img,theta)
     mask = rotate(mask,theta)
   return img, mask

if __name__== '__main__':

  input_size = 512
  data_dir = '../data/carvana-image-masking-challenge'
  np.random.seed(1987)

  df_train = pd.read_csv(join(data_dir,'train_masks.csv'),usecols=['img'])
  df_train['img_id']=df_train['img'].map(lambda s:s.split('.')[0])
  df_train.head(3)


 img_ids=df_train['img_id'].values
 np.random.shuffle(img_ids)
 img_id=img_ids[0]
 img,mask=get_image_and_mask(img_id)
 print((img.shape,mask.shape))
 plot_img_and_mask(img,mask)

 img_flip,mask_flip = random_flip(img,mask,u=1)
 print((img_flip.shape,mask_flip.shape))
 plot_img_and_mask_transformed(img,mask,img_flip,mask_flip)
```

### OUTPUT

```
    Using TensorFlow backend.
    C:\Users\JamesJohnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- packages\keras_preprocessing\image.py:492: UserWarning: grayscale is deprecated. Please use color_mode = "grayscale"
   warnings.warn('grayscale is deprecated. Please use '
  > ((512, 512, 3), (512, 512, 1))
  > ((512, 512, 3), (512, 512))
  [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
   ...
   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "Augmentation.py", line 94, in <module>
 plot_img_and_mask_transformed(img,mask,img_flip,mask_flip)
 File "Augmentation.py", line 36, in plot_img_and_mask_transformed
 print(mask_tr[:,:,0])
 IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: Please post the code where you use the function, e.g. `img, mask = random_flip(img, mask)`

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I have posted the code. WIll that be sufficient?

Comment: One time you print `mask`, next time `mask_tr`...

Comment: mask_tr is basically the output of flipping the image

Comment: That's what I asked for: a statement like `???, mask_tr = random_flip(img, mask)`

Comment: I suspect the shape of the mask is really (512,512)...

Comment: @s326280 Please print out the shape of your mask: `print(mask.shape)`.  I am highly confident that @MarkSetchell is correct.  You will most likely not see a third dimension in the shape, which is why you are getting that error.  To solve this, you need to make sure to add a singleton dimension to the third dimension if you have a 2D mask: `mask = mask[...,None]`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, The shape is posted in the output section. Please have a look at it. The line starts with '>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like OpenCV dumps the singleton dimension when you flip the mask. You'll need to reintroduce it after you flip.

```
mask_flip = mask_flip[..., None]
```

A more convenient way is to modify your method so the mask is returned with the singleton dimension after you flip in case you lose it. This way you don't have to do this every time you flip and the method takes care of that instead.

```
def random_flip(img,mask,u=0.5):
    # Why do we have to check less than u
    if np.random.random() < u: 
        img = cv.flip(img,0)
        mask = cv.flip(mask,0)
        if len(mask.shape) == 2:
            mask = mask[..., None]
        return img, mask
```

BTW as a minor note, you have a comment that asks why you have to check for less than `u` in the method.   Remember that the `np.random.random` method generates a value between 0 and 1 uniformly.  Suppose you chose `u = 0.3`.  This means that there is a 30% chance that you will choose a value between between 0 and 0.3 and a 70% chance that you will choose a value between 0.3 and 1.  Loosely, this means that if `u = 0.3`, there is a 30% chance that the `if` condition is run and you thus flip the image and mask.  Therefore, the `u` controls the probability that a flip of the image and mask will happen.